# Selecting random file but then deleting it

Tags: javascript, node.js, random

I have some code that selects a random file from a folder then logs it, after its done logging I want it to be deleted but I can't seem to delete it.

The path to the randomly selected file is stored as a variable.

```
const trash = require('trash');
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    files_memes = fs.readdirSync('/Users/jackb/Desktop/pup/Pictures/reddit_sub_memes')
var filename = (random_file());
var imgPATH = path.join(__dirname, '/Users/jackb/Desktop/pup/Pictures/reddit_sub_memes/' + filename);
const del = require('del');

function random_file(){
  var allFiles = (files_memes)
  return allFiles[Math.floor(Math.random() * allFiles.length)];
}
console.log(filename);
console.log(imgPATH);
(async () => {
    const deletedPaths = await del(['imagePATH']);

    console.log('Deleted files and directories:\n', deletedPaths.join('\n'));
})();
```

I expect the logged file to be deleted.

Comment: shouldn't `await del(['imagePATH'])` be `await del([ imagePATH ])` - meaning delete the file whose path is in the variable `imagePath`, not some non existent file called "imagePath"?

Comment: I've tried both ways and each time nothing gets deleted. I don't understand why it doesn't work because the variable is displayed in the console and clearly shows a real path.

Comment: I suspect including `__dirname` at the start of `imgPath` would cause a problem  unless executed with  the root of the system disk as the working directory. However I can't explain the log output but glad to see you've got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed this line of code

```
const deletedPaths = await del(['imagePATH']);
```

to

```
const deletedPaths = await 
del('/Users/jackb/Desktop/pup/Pictures/reddit_sub_memes/' + filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have all the file path strings in an array, and use _.sample() in lodash, which help you pick the random value from an array.

Comment: I would prefer not using an Array as everything works so far I just can't delete the file using the variable which the value equals the path of the file.